# File to import not found or unreadable: ~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, sass

When I try to compile my SCSS to CSS I get this error:

```
/usr/local/bin/scss --no-cache --update app.scss:app.css
  error app.scss (Line 9: File to import not found or unreadable: ~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The bootstrap file is actually in the node_modules folder and the import should work as well:

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

Comment: set extaination to bootstrap `@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.css';`

Comment: that doesn't help unfortunately cause I got SCSS bootstrap. I also tried to set it to .scss. Doesn't work

Comment: do not use `~` USE `../../`

Comment: What is your root folder's hierarchy? We can not guess that.